# c strcmp() with array of strings

Tags: c, arrays, string

I am trying to count the amount of times which any word is repeated in the words[] array. I already have i, j, num_words and the words array initialized. The words array is type char *words[n]. The frequency[] array runs parallel to the words[] array and keeps track of the number of times each word appears. The program compiles but when it runs i get a segmentation fault. The problem is coming from the following section of code:

```
    int frequency[1000] = {0};
    for(i = 0; i < num_words; i++){
            for(j = i+1; j < num_words; j++){
                    if(strcmp(words[i], words[j]) == 0){
                          freq[i]++;
                    }
            }
    }
```

I've been playing around with this for a while but i have no idea what is wrong with this bit of code.

Comment: What value is num_words?

Comment: What is connection between `int frequency[1000]`, `i < num_words`, and`freq[i]`? Looks like some kind of pastiche. Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem.

Comment: At least add  assert(num_words < 1000)

Comment: Even when you get this code working it will count the number of times a word occurs after each instance of it.

Comment: n = num_words = 1000 (max number of words, not actual). Sorry, forgot that when moving the code over to stackexchange.

Comment: The problem may occur here, but does not originate here.  Suspect `words[]` or how it is assinged..  IAC, voting to close per [@WeatherVane comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40323610/c-strcmp-with-array-of-strings/40323802?noredirect=1#comment67902844_40323610).

Comment: You need to post all your code. Preferrably cut down as much as possible to bare minimum, but make sure it still compiles and still crashes.

Comment: You want to make yourself comfortable with using a debugger. Its helps and it's fun! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You have to increment the `freq` for both `i` and `j` as follows:

```
for (i = 0; i < num_words; i++)
    for (j = i + 1; j < num_words; j++) 
        if (strcmp(words[i], words[j]) == 0)
        {
            freq[i]++;
            freq[j]++;
        }
```

Furthermore, you are initializing `freq` to zero. So each letter occurs at least zero times, which makes no sense. You probably want to initialize to 1.

```
for (i = 0; i < num_words; i++)
    freq[i] = 1;
```

*Is it `freq` or `frequency`? you have two different variables in your code*

Testing

```
int main()
{
    char *words[] = { "1", "2", "3", "1", "1", "4"};
    int i, j;
    const int num_words = 6;
    int freq[num_words] = { 0 };

    for (i = 0; i < num_words; i++) 
        freq[i] = 1;

    for (i = 0; i < num_words; i++)
        for (j = i + 1; j < num_words; j++) 
            if (strcmp(words[i], words[j]) == 0)
            {
                freq[i]++;
                freq[j]++;
            }

    for (i = 0; i < num_words; i++)
        printf("%d ", freq[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

result

> 3 1 1 3 3 1